# Using struct in c++, Can't figure out the problem

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, reference

This is what i'm trying to do:

> Implement a structure Employee. An employee has a name (a char *) and
> a salary (a double). Write a default constructor, a constructor with
> two parameters (name and salary), and methods char* getName() double
> getSalary() to return the name and salary. Write a small global
> function TestEmployee() to test your structure.

And this is what i've done so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

//Implement a structure Employee.
struct Employee
{
private:
    //An employee has a name (a char *) and a salary (a double).
    char *EmpName;
    double EmpSalary;
public:
    //default constructor
    Employee()
    {
        this->EmpName = new char[100];
        this->EmpSalary = 0.00;
    }
    //a constructor with two parameters (name and salary),
    Employee(char* name_, double salary_)
    {
        do
        {
            this->EmpName = name_;
            this->EmpSalary = salary_;
        
        }while(salary_<0);
    }
    //char* getName() to return the name
    char* getName()
    {
        return this->EmpName;
    }
    //double getSalary() to return the salary.
    double getSalary()
    {
        return this->EmpSalary;
    }
};

//Write a small global function TestEmployee() to test your structure.
void TestEmployee()
{
    //Employee employee_;
    char* empName = new char[100];
    double empSalary;

    cout<<"Creating a new employee.\nPlease type the name:"<<endl;
    cin>>empName;
    cout<<"Please specify the salary:"<<endl;
    cin>>empSalary;
    cout<<"New employee has been created."<<endl;

    Employee employee_(empName, empSalary);

    cout<<"Name of employee: "<<endl;
    cout<<employee_.getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Salary: "<<endl;
    cout<<employee_.getSalary()<<endl;
    cout<<"Thank you for testing structure Employee."<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    TestEmployee();
}
```

I can't seem to find the error, this program isn't working. This is the output it's giving:

[image]

When this is the output it's supposed to have:

[image]

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Here `this->EmpName = name_;`, you are not copying the name, just the pointer to the name

Comment: @Damien How should i to correct this?

Comment: Another issue: When you type *Larry Bird*, Larry is taken as the name and Bird as the sallary ! You should use `getline`, in conjonction with `std::string`. In addition, you have a memory leak in your function, solved with `std::string`

Comment: @idclev463035818 we've been instructed to use char and not string, it would've been easier with string though.

Comment: @MahreenAthar _we've been instructed to use char and not string_ Then you need either fixed size char arrays in your struct, or allocate and manage dynamic memory yourself.

Comment: you must have been told **how** to use char arrays also, otherwise the assignment makes no sense at all. You should have been told how to copy a c-string for example. Maybe review your lecture material

Comment: @Damien yes i used string instead of char. It worked thanks.

Comment: @Damien Also how do i fix this program with using char and not string? Just curious.

Comment: Most of the hints have been given: 1. Use [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to read the name 2. Avoid memory leak, by using a fixed size for the array `char empName[100]` (or `delete[]` at the end) 3. Check for positivity of the salary when reading, not when creating the struct instance. 4. Use the proper function to copy a `char *`: [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). I hope avoiding nothing, not tested